# Mac Studio stopped recognising Apple wired keyboard

Tags: keyboard, usb, startup

last week my Mac Studio suddenly stopped recognising my wired Apple keyboard. This happens after a reboot or when it was shut down - at first, it was enough to unplug it once and then it was recognised again. Next day it was three times and today it worked briefly after maybe 30, but after another restart stopped working again.

At first I thought it might be a software issue with Karabiner. So I have updated the system and Karabiner to latest versions, reinstalled it and also removed it completely, but the problem persists.

I know for a fact that the keyboard works, because:

- it works instantly on MacBook Air, MacBook Pro and Windows PC
- this model has two USB ports in it and every other keyboard I plug in works, so there shouldn't definitely be any power or cable issue
- I can see it listed in USB devices that are connected as "Keyboard HUB" which is the same name Windows gave me

I have tried every USB port, USB hub and a small USB to USB-C reduction, booting in safe mode - but it just wont get recognised... any other keyboard works.

Googling didnt amount to much either. Is there something else I might try? Maybe some kind of preference reset so it will forget it was ever plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried every USB port, USB hub and a small USB to USB-C reduction, booting in safe mode - but it just wont get recognised... any other keyboard works.

**Your keyboard is dying**.

You’ve done enough diagnostics to eliminate any other possibility. The fact that “any other keyboard works” tells you that your keyboard has failed/is failing.

Comment: Gave it to my girlfriend for now. If it is in fact dying, I wonder how long it will work on her macbook

Comment: It’s impossible to predict that. Without putting hands on, it’s impossible to know which part of your keyboard is faulty. Likely it’s an electronic component on the PCB.

Comment: Neat, now you can blame your girlfriend when she kills that working keyboard you so kindly gave her :-)

Comment: Careful with the advice from @HighPerformanceMark.  You might be able to get her to get you a new keyboard, but you might be using it from the couch or worse, she could appropriate your Mac get you a Windows laptop.